# Register service in startup class when signing in

Tags: .net-core

I am developing an application with multiple tenants. Each tenant can be associated with a user to identify the database that it will have access to, through the connection string that is stored in the database.
The problem I am having is that I only identify this connection string at the moment the user logs in, however I need to register this connection string when the StartUp class is executed.

I tried to do this using session variables, I got the ConfigureServices method of the StartUp class to run again with the correct value, but I can not get this new configuration to take effect.

```
services.AddScoped<IDapperContext>(s => new DapperContext(connectionString));
```

I guess I need to rebuild for the new setting to take effect.
How can I do this?
Am I on the right path?
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recently read this article, which talks about injecting the HTTPContext into your service.

https://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/

Once you have the context, you can get the authenticated user, and retrieve your connection string from a second DB or source that maps users to databases.  You would have to configure your context options during construction of the context, in order to control the connection string for the context as a scoped service.

You might want to consider using a context factory instead that does this for you.

The code in startup.cs would add a context for the database with your connection strings, and then your factory would accept that as an injected dependency.  Your factory would also take in IHttpContextAccessor as a dependency giving you access to the user in the context.  Together you could then obtain the connection string, and wire up the DbContextOptions to pass to a new instance of your context.

This seems like the easiest approach for DI to me.